# When should PyTest tests be part of a Class, and when should they be standalone methods?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I've got some tests which are using fixtures for some setup and teardown, and I'm not sure about the best way to structure it.

The examples in the doco show both standalone and class groupings of tests

These two examples demonstrate, at a very basic level, the options, and return the same result.

1. standalone

   ```
   import pytest


   @pytest.fixture
   def other():
       # setup
       yield
       # teardown

   def test_one():
       assert 1 == 1

   def test_two():
       assert 0 != 1
   ```
2. Grouped in a Class

   ```
   import pytest


   class TestClass:

       @pytest.fixture
       def other(self):
           # setup
           yield  
           # teardown

       def test_one(self):
           assert 1 == 1

       def test_two(self):
           assert 0 != 1
   ```

I want to understand when I should use each option, and what the benefits of each are? Are there hard and fast rules, or is it a matter of taste, and so on.

Thanks
Simon.